# Reading a CSV file my date formats keep changing?

Tags: php, csv

I'm reading a flat-text CSV file with `fgetcsv()` and extracting the date from one of the columns, like this:

```
$visit_date_title = 'SVDT';
while (($data = fgetcsv($this->handle, 2000, ",")) !== false) {
    $this->row++;

    //Set header columns
    if ($this->row == 1) {
        if(($visit_date_col = $this->get_column_number($data, $visit_date_title)) === false) break;
        $minimum_cols = ($visit_date_col > $minimum_cols) ? $visit_date_col : $minimum_cols;
        continue;
    }

    $this->visitDate = $data[$visit_date_col];

    $this->logprintf(__LINE__, "NOTE  : Received >" . $this->visitDate. "<");
}
```

I use the following data...

```
SVDT,NOTHING
12/11/2019,0
13/11/2019,0
14/11/2019,0
02/12/2019,0
```

Why do I get varying date formats, even just on reading the text?! I see this...

```
2019-12-12T14:57:48+00:00 : [line  376] : NOTE  : Received >2019/12/11<   <===
2019-12-12T14:57:48+00:00 : [line  376] : NOTE  : Received >13/11/2019<
2019-12-12T14:57:48+00:00 : [line  376] : NOTE  : Received >14/11/2019<
2019-12-12T14:57:48+00:00 : [line  376] : NOTE  : Received >2019/02/12<   <===
```

Is there a way to avoid this meddling and just get the data?

Comment: It's assuming the value is American format (m/d/Y) (English I think uses `-` and not `/`) but when it gets to `13/11/2019` - it can't convert 13 to a month so it decides it must be an English date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a actual/correct date from `CSV` file, so no problem in that. So at the end of getting output and assigning a value of date to your `visitDate` variable, you format a standard date format like below. Hope it helps you

```
 // change date format here

$dateVisited = str_replace("/", "-", $data[$visit_date_col]);

$this->visitDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dateVisited));

$this->logprintf(__LINE__, "NOTE  : Received >" . $this->visitDate. "<");
```